# How to parse the web page to change simplexml_import_dom into DOMXPath?

Tags: php, parsing

All the links in the web page `http://php.net` were extracted with simplexml_import_dom in code1.

```
code1
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://php.net');
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
$nodes = $xml->xpath('//a[@href]');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node['href'], "<br />\n";
}
?>
```

Now i want parse the web page with DOMXPath,change simplexml_import_dom in code1
into DOMXPath in code2,there is a bug in code2 ,how to fix it?

```
code2
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('http://php.net');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//a[@href]');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node['href'], "<br />\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Describe the bug and someone might even answer your question ;-)

Comment: SteAp ,please try it as the code said.

Comment: Sorry, you didn't even understand my hint. You know the bug and you don't exactly describe it - using words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

returned data from query is objects not array!

if you get warning like :

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag nav invalid in Entity
```

in output you can add this line before loadHTML function call

it because of html5 tag used in document

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
```

code :

```
$html =  file_get_contents('http://php.net');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//a[@href]');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->getAttribute("href"), "<br />\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To parse all a href tags:

```
$sHtml = file_get_contents('http://php.net');
// var_dump( $sHtml );
$oDom = new DOMDocument( '1.0', 'utf-8' );
// Supress <DOCTYPE> notices
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$oDom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $sHtml );
// var_dump( $oDom );
$oXPath = new DOMXPath( $oDom );
$oNodes = $oXPath->query( '//a/@href' );
foreach( $oNodes as $oNode )
{
    // var_dump( $oNode );
    echo $oNode->nodeValue, "<br />\n";
}
// Supress <DOCTYPE> notices
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
```